# word for burrowing, but by a plant rather than an animal

Tags: synonyms, plant-physiology

I would like to describe how deeply a tree's roots go underground. Burrowing is a term used for animals. Is it appropriate to use it in describing the extent to which a certain tree can dig its roots into the ground? What would be the correct term?

Comment: I wouldn't use burrow for underground growth. It may be used in popular writing, but it's not scientifically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Burrow' **is** also used for roots, but 'reach' (to a depth of) is far more common.

Answer (score 2):

In a scientific context, I would use either *reach* or *extend* or *burrow* as you have. To describe the depth the roots reach to for example:

> The specimen's roots extended 10 meters below the surface.

In a less formal context, I might also go for [*delve*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/delve):

> delve (dɛlv) vb (mainly intr; often foll by in or into)
>
> 1. to inquire or research deeply or intensively (for information, etc): he delved in the Bible for quotations.
> 2. to search or rummage (in a drawer, the pockets, etc)
> 3. (Zoology) (esp of an animal) to dig or burrow deeply (into the ground, etc)
> 4. (also tr) to dig or turn up (earth, a garden, etc), as with a spade

Something like:

> The plant's roots delved deep into the ground in search of water.

Answer (score 0):

I think *penetrate* is the word you're after:

> The willow roots had penetrated the foundation.
>
> The roots of certain trees can penetrate to amazing depths.